# Teamcity - Selenium Grid environment - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, teamcity, selenium-grid

I am running a small selenium project using grid setup. All is fine when I run locally which has the hub and the node running in the same machine. What I did next was kept the hub running in my local machine and tried running the test through teamcity. I presume that the test will run in one of the build agents. When I kick start the build job, I got the following exception. Not sure what the issue is.

```
Test(s) failed. System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server ----> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : A connection attempt failed because the connected 
party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.6.121:80 at 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Also, the team city build agent IP is 192.168.7.132 whereas I am getting a message that it is unable to contact 192.168.6.121

Is there something happening which I am not aware of.

The selenium server is up and running in my local machine. and all is fine at the server end.

Any pointers will be much helpful